# how to convert value in array to be stringg and number to be a sentence

Tags: javascript, sql, arrays, database, loops

how to convert this array `['myname', 'myhobby', 1]` to be `"myname", "hobby", 1`
1 must be a number, is that possible ?? I want to create value for push it on database , sqlite

so when I call parameter of `(name, hobby, age)` and the value must be `('myname', 'myhobby', 1)`

myname TEXT
hobby TEXT
age INTEGER

is that possible ??

Comment: You can use `parseInt()` to make it a number

Comment: if you use `parseInt()` you would have to check for `isNaN()` to return either string or number.  `isNaN(parseInt(var)) ? var : parseInt(var)`

Comment: With the given array, `['myname', 'myhobby', 1]`, the value of `1` is of type `number`. You need to check and onvert the value to an Integer type on whatever backend you are using, not on the client side.

Comment: I have many kinds length of values, so I should to make sure each values to be string and number, but how can I make the array into the string sentence to use on VALUES (...values)  ?

Comment: at the end of the day, you would have an array container of want you want to insert or update into the db. I hope you realize having each values of strings and number in a variable equals to an array container.  best bet is to map your array to give you a collection of different data types and reference them using index position in your db statement.

Comment: can u give me example

Comment: `let newArray = oldArray.map(item => { return isNaN(parseInt(item)) ? item : parseInt(item) });`

In your values, reference as `(newArray[0], newArray[1], newArray[2])`

Comment: as I said I have different length of values on my database, should I write arr[0] , arr[1] ? how about if the values of that database till 10 columns?? it gonna be undefined,